# How do I replace the ' (quotation) character using a MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, atom-feed

I'm trying to create and XML feed with the result set of a SQL query. One of the fields contains ' characters which is causing an error in the resulting XML file.

How do I replace the ' character. I've read posts that suggest something like

```
Replace(my_column,'''','')
```

But this throws up a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET your_column = REPLACE(your_column, '\'', '&apos;');
```

But then again, I wonder why it's necessary to do that in DB, and not in the output code.

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
select replace('abc''def','''','')
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2385)

Answer (score 0):

Use `&apos;` in place of `'`.
This will work:

```
Replace(my_column,"'",'&apos;')
```